# What is iOS's block_destroy_helper function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I noticed a function named `block_destroy_helper` in this crash log from my iOS app. I want to know more what is this function, but I can't find any useful information. I just want to know the followings:

1. What is this function doing?
2. What event can trigger a call to this function?
3. When I reproduce this crash on Debug build, this crash was an index out of bound error in my own source code. How could this error turned into `block_destroy_helper` in Release build?

For crash log below, MyModule is a module in my app written in Swift. MyModule uses another library AsyncDisplayKit written in Objective-C.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000106d5e7ec

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  MyModule                       0x967ec block_destroy_helper.26 + 5740
1  MyModule                       0x97048 block_destroy_helper.26 + 7880
2  AsyncDisplayKit                0x2ee28 -[ASCollectionView collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:] + 208
3  UIKitCore                      0x3006e0 -[UICollectionView _selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:deselectPrevious:performCustomSelectionAction:] + 816
4  UIKitCore                      0x54c4d4 -[UICollectionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 480
```

**UPDATE**

Finally, I can reproduce the crash. But when I reproduce this crash on Debug build, the crash was from my code, and was an Array index out of bound error (as shown below).

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x32cb4 closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 356
1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x32a1c closure #1 in closure #1 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 192
2  libswiftCore.dylib             0x323bc _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 228
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x12274 _ContiguousArrayBuffer.capacity.getter + 274
4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x15d14 Array.subscript.getter + 84
5  MyModule                       0x135d08 $s9MyModule16HomeMenuListNodeC010collectionF0_15didSelectItemAtySo012ASCollectionF0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtF + 872
6  MyModule                       0x137d64 $s9MyModule16HomeMenuListNodeC010collectionF0_15didSelectItemAtySo012ASCollectionF0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFTo + 136
7  AsyncDisplayKit                0x763a4 -[ASCollectionView collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:] + 272
8  UIKitCore                      0x2f2c64 -[UICollectionView _selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:deselectPrevious:performCustomSelectionAction:] + 1020
9  UIKitCore                      0x666864 -[UICollectionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 612
```

Comment: the function is part of code generated by clang (compiler) to destroy a block closure. You may want to provide more details if you want help with tracking down the root cause of the problem. I.e. the part where your module gets callback from `ASCollectionView` (if you have set it up)

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I finally be able to reproduce the error. But I found out it was an error in my own source code. Please have a look in my updated question. Now I wonder why my app crash in compiler generated code in Release build.

Comment: Code optimisation can make some unexpected changes, you can turn it off  for the release build in Xcode build settings and compare the crash logs again.